# obtain facebook page access token from server

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-page

I need to obtain a facebook page access token on the server.

From what I've read to obtain a page access token you must first obtain a user access token with the manage_pages permission then make a separate call to "me/accounts" to get the page access token.

The problem with this is the application I'm developing will automatically be publishing content to a Facebook page from the server. That being said obtaining the user access token from the backend is a problem.

Ideally I would like to programmaticly obtain the user access token then the page access token completely on the backend for the ability to automatically publish content to the page.

Any suggestions on how this can be done from the server side?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get page `access_token` without authentication of user and `manage_pages` permissions granting.

Authenticating as a Page guide states:

> First you need to authenticate a User, and obtain a User Access Token. To do this, please follow the server-side or client-side auth flows for the mobile web and desktop web, or the native iOS or native Android authentication flows.

Refer to [Authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [Authenticating as a Page guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) for details.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that it is possible to get a page access token that does not expire? Some posts say 60 days.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/
"Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission."

Comment: @AjSavino, yep, using user's extended `access_token` allow to get page `access_token` that doesn't expire.